# Is there any difference between duplica and replica

Tags: filesystems, replication, microsoft-distributed-file-system

I've read many papers and source code about distributed system and there are many "duplica"s and "replica"s. It seems having the same meaning.

Is there any difference between these two words?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble finding any papers which refer to "duplicas" either in my paper archive or on Google Scholar, although I've found a bunch which say "duplicates"/"duplication".  If that's what you meant, yes, they refer to the same thing.